# Adding attachments to NotesDocument

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, lotus

I am trying to add the inline image file attachment to NotesDocument object in C#. I am facing issue when system is having Lotus Notes version below 8.5.

Here is my sample code

```
NotesRichTextItem obj_notesRichTextItem = MailDoc.CreateRichTextItem("Attachment");

NotesEmbeddedObject obj_notesEmbeddedObject =obj_notesRichTextItem.EmbedObject(EMBED_TYPE.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "",AttachPath,"Attachment");
```

I am getting following error

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt

Please suggest some solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The name is optional and not a valid argument for attachments. It's been a long time since I last used C#, but if I recall correctly, that should be handled with `System.Type.Missing` (unless there's something else for optional arguments without defaults now).